# How to compare a variable returned from other function with a matching row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I am trying to compare the variable $manager_id is present in pr_resignation_requests as managerid column. If present then return the row else dont. But somehow this query  is not working. Tried many things but doesn't work. I know my where clause has the error,

Error is :

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

`SELECT g.*, userids, resignations_date, reason_type, requested_date, last_status, date_last_status, agreed_date, exit_details, exit_checklist, firstname, lastname, managerid FROM (pr_resignation_requests as g) JOIN pr_users_details as ud ON ud.userid = g.userids WHERE`1`= 'managerid'`

My query is :

```html
function get_resignation_request($id=0)
{
global $USER;
$post_arr = $this->input->post();
$manager_id = $this->get_value_by_id('managerid','users',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
$this->db->select('g.*,userids,resignations_date,reason_type,requested_date,last_status,date_last_status,agreed_date,exit_details,exit_checklist,firstname,lastname,managerid');
$this->db->from('pr_resignation_requests as g'); 
$this->db->where($manager_id, managerid); 
//$where = "$manager_id='1'";

 //$this->db->where($where);
//$this->db->join('pr_resignation_requests as uds','uds.managerid = ".$manager_id" ');

//$this->db->where($manager_id, managerid); 
//$this->db->where($manager_id = managerid); 
//$this->db->join($this->myTables['pr_users_details'].' as ud','ud.userid = g.userid');
$this->db->join('pr_users_details as ud','ud.userid = g.userids');

//$this->db->join('pr_users as uds','uds.id = g.managerid');
/*$this->db->join('pr_resignation_type as gt','gt.id = g.sr_type');*/
$query=$this->db->get(); 

$return = $query->result_array();

return $return;
}
```

Comment: whats this `$this->db->where($manager_id, managerid);` - `managerid` a constant or a string, because there are no `quotes`

Comment: this is column name of pr_resignation_requests table...

Comment: I want to do something like $manager_id == managerid(of pr_resignation_requests). But have no clue how to achieve this

Comment: This is wrong `WHERE1= 'managerid'` the column name is `1`? that is your error after all.  `1` is not equal to `managerid` as a string.

Comment: no you are getting it wrong, $manager_id has the value 1 and i am trying to compare it with managerid column of pr_resignation_requests table

Comment: It's not me that has anything wrong, that is clearly what you have in the question, and what the error says...  If it's wrong then it's your code that has it wrong...  Clearly `Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'` and `WHERE 1 = ..` is the error, is it not..

Comment: ok.. thank you... Nobody likes being wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. In where clause first parameter is table name not the value

```
$query = $this->db->where('managerid', $manager_id);
```

Comment: What I said in the comments.  But as the OP pointed out I have it wrong.. lol

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix i am still in doubt whether he understood or not.

Comment: As they say, you can lead the horse to water but you cant make him drink.